# in include if i use "test.h" is the same with "path/test.h"?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gsoap

I am working in ubuntu under c++ language.

I have a question: i use `#include"header.h"`. Is this the same with `/path/header.h`? I ask you this question because as I've seen is not the same thing. Need some explications.

I ask you this question because I've downloaded and install gsoap on my computer. I added all the necessary dependencies in a folder and I've tried to run the app without installing gsoap ...on a different computer. I had some errors..i forgot to add stdsoap2.h file...I will add it today..in my folder..

Comment: Please put some effort in improving the phrasing and formatting of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `header.h` is in the directory `path/`, then `#include "header.h"` will work for those header and source files (which `#include` header.h which happen to be in the same directory as `header.h` (`path/`).

On the other hand, if you are `#include`-ing `header.h` in a file that is in a different directory than `path/`, then the above way would not work. To make it work, you can try 2 different approaches:

1. `#include` the complete path to `header.h`. Your `#include` will look something like: 
   `#include "path/header.h"`
2. Include the `path/` directory to the `makefile`. This will get `g++` to look for `header.h` in those directories as well. This can be done like so (in the makefile):
   `g++ <some parameters> -Ipath/ -c main.cpp -o main.o` (assuming `header.h` is called from within `main.cpp`). If you choose this way, then the `#include` will also change, like so:
   `#include <header.h>`. Note the use of the `-I` flag as a parameter to g++. That flag tells g++ to look into additional directories as well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is it depends:

If you have "path/" added to your *include path* then including only "header.h" will work because then compiler already knows the path to lookup for your header files, if not 
then you have to include entire path "path/header.h"  so the compiler knows where to look for the header file.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same, conceptually. The results, however, could be the same. It depends on how you tell your compiler to find headers (the `-I` flag in `g++`). If you would compile with `-I /path/`, then you'd find `/path/header.h` with `#include "header.h"`. If you do not use that include path flag, then you'd have to write `#include "/path/header.h"`.